# how can i find who is using my website under the other domain

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess, google-analytics

i m using wordpress 
last 2 days i m getting abnormal traffic to my server 
but there is not much traffic on my website

so some1 other using my website under the their domain name

i got like 85.000 uniqe visitors to my server

but the problem is  i have statcounter and google analytic on my website

stats counter and analytic doesnt count  this visitors

i have also advertising on my website   there is also nothing

i delete all website and redirect to 404.php
and i add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (top.location!= self.location) {
            top.location = "http://www.example.com";
        }
    </script>
```

actualy if they do run under the other domain  this code must help to get visitors to 404.php and analytic must  count it 
this code also not helping to me

how can i find which domain is using my  website and  block it

in the server access logs there is also nothing about refered all traffic is working  like  under the my domain

Comment: _"i m getting abnormal traffic to my server but there is not much traffic on my website"_ --- do you not have server tools to help with this?

Comment: its not  fake traffic ..   its like they are real visitors  searching  watching  videos but not on my domain

Comment: Is it the Google analytics stats you are looking at? Can you include a picture of your Acquisition -> Overview page? Specifically I want the referrals. So that would be good too or better with both

Comment: Andreas  they are not showing in  analytic and statcounter . even i put  livechat  to look how many people online on website .   i see just visitors  under the my domain

Comment: i think somebody is hotlinking your images....https://www.google.nl/search?q=hotlinking+detect

Comment: its not just image ..   they are using whole website ..

Comment: Where are you seeing these visitors? If not in Google Analytics what program or log are you finding them? If you check your server logs you should be able to see every IP that is accessing your site and figure out which one is most common. If one IP is the offender you can do a WHOIS IP lookup to identify the owner of that IP.

Comment: in server  logs ..  and there is not one ip .. yesterday was 85.000 uniq ip adress